# Error: Socket hang up cannot read property result[2]

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I've tried to insert the data from webform to neo4j database but my record has been inserted but at the same time i got this error socket hang up.
And Match query doesn't work help out for this problem

```
app.post('/insert',function (req,res){
     var email = req.body['email'];
     var password = req.body['password'];
     var query = [
             'CREATE (user:test {newUser})'
                 // 'RETURN user'
            ]
     var params = {
      newUser: {
      email: email,
      password: password,
     }
};                          
     db.cypher({
     query: query,
     params: params
}, 
    function(err,user){
        if(err) console.log(err) ;
        console.log(user);
        res.send("Record has been Inserted ");
    });
})

app.get('/json', function(req,res){
   db.cypher({
    query: 'MATCH (user:test {email: {email}})  RETURN user'
    }, function (err, results) {
    if (err)  console.log(err);
    var result = results[2];
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No user found.');
    } else {
        var user = result['user'];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));
    }
});
})
```

Comment: You don't provide the `email` parameter when executing the `MATCH` query, so it can't work. As for the error, why don't you add it to the question?

Comment: This is the error i'm getting { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }    var result = results[2]; even if i added the params i've got the same error.   db.cypher({
    query: 'MATCH (user:test) RETURN user',
    params:{
        'email':'123@gmail.com'
    }